# Many to Many Relationship with 2 pivot table data search

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

```
Skills
-------
id  name
1   PHP
2   Laravel

Qualifications
-----------------
id  name
1   MBA
2   Graduate
3   Post Graduate

students
------------
id  name
1   John
2   Smith

 2 pivot tables

student_skills

student_id  skill_id
1           1
1           2
2           1

student_qualifications

tutor_id    qualification_id
1           2
1           2
2           2
```

In front-end the user can select multiple qualifications(checkboxes) and skills(checkboxes) according to the options selected we need to display the data.

**For Example:** How to get students with qualification graduate and MBA and skills Laravel and PHP

Comment: what details you need @AchrafKhouadja

Comment: Like, what is the actual question?  Where is your code?  See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you can do it ( it might be inaccurate due to the lack of details in your question but it should give you an idea)

(i think you better use a Mutli-select box instead of check-boxes for skills & qualification)

Assuming you want to search student by skills & qualification 
And that you have the right Relations methods inside your models

```
  //Don't forget to import Students model at top of the controller
public function whatever(Request $request)
    {
    $data = Student::with('qualifications', 'skills');

     // assuming that the form will pass an array of skills names
     //if the form passes an array of ID's of skills it becomes easier

    if (!empty($request->skills)) {
        foreach ($request->skills as $skill) {
            $data->whereHas('skills', function ($query) use ($skill) {
                $query->where('id', $skill);
            })->get();
        }
    }

       // same goes for qualifications
    if (!empty($request->qualifications)) {
        foreach ($request->qualifications as $qualification) {
            $data->whereHas('qualifications', function ($query) use ($skill) {
                $query->where('id', $qualification);
            })->get();
        }
    }

    // execute the query now
   $data->get(); // or pagniate(10)
}
```

if you are passing an array of ID's instead of names

```
   if (!empty($request->skills)) {
            $data->whereHas('skills', function ($query) use ($skills)                   {
                $query->whereIn('id', $skills);
            })->get();
    }
```

same goes for qualifications.

I hope you get the point here, you can Sort and stuff , this might not be the exact thing u need, but It will help you a lot if you get it.

Comment: Its working thanks for your quick response @AchrafKhouadja

Comment: great, mark this as the answer and upote it if you like. glad for you.